# How postgresql return a data set like the follows?

Tags: postgresql

Just like the below function. I don't know how to return a set of inside parameter in postgresql?

```
create or replace function g_i(num int) 
returns setof integer 
as $$
declare 
    i int;
begin
      while i < $1 loop
        select i; -- How to write statements here?
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: create or replace function g_i(num int) returns setof integer as $$
declare 
i int;
begin
  while i < $1 loop
    select i; -- How to write statements here?
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function g_i(num int) 
returns setof integer 
as $$
declare 
    i int;
begin
        i := 0;
      while i< $1 loop
        i := i+1;
        return query select i; 
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```